# Write an integration test for all the layout links, including the proper behavior for logged-in and non-logged-in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

im working with railstutorial.org, im currently at 9th chapter, doing exercises. I have to write an integration test for all the layout links, including the proper behavior for logged-in and non-logged-in users.
There's an exercise:
Write an integration test for all the layout links, including the proper behavior for logged-in and non-logged-in users. Hint: Add to the test in Listing 5.25 using the log_in_as helper.

This is 5.25 Listing:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
  end
end
```

This is the line i came up with to solve the exercise:

```
assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path || users_path
```

My tests are green, but did I am not sure if I understood the exercise right, and If i solved it.

So my question is, how do I write the test described in the exercise, thanks

Comment: i don't understand your question. what's up with that line?

Comment: I edited the original post, maybe now it is more clear what I need

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like this:

```
# Not logged in so a "Login" link will be present
assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
# Login
log_in_as(@user)
# Go to root
get root_path
# Now logged in so a "Login" link won't be present
assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
# Now logged in so a "Logout" link will be present
assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
# Now logged in so a "Users" link will be present
assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path
# Now logged in so a "Accounts" link will be present
assert_select 'a[href=?]', '#', text: 'Accounts'
```

Don't forget to include the following just after `class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`:

```
def setup
  @user = users(:michael)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working through this rails tutorial as well. Here is the full test I came up with. I may have went a bit extreme here, but the exercise does state that all links should be tested both logged in and logged out. This includes the user's profile and Settings links at `user_path` and `edit_user_path` respectively. One step that helped me was to actually look at the site both as a logged in and non-logged in user and even pull up the source to determine the full list of links as indicated by the `a href` tags in the source. Also, make sure you `get root_path` after your `log_in_as(@user)`. This will save you the confusion and headache that I suffered.

```
test "layout links for logged-in and non-logged-in users" do
  get root_path
  assert_template 'static_pages/home'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
  assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
  log_in_as(@user)
  get root_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
  assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", "#", text: "Account"
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_path(@user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My steps are setup a user, test for layout links before login, use `log_in_as`helper to login the user, use `follow_redirect!` to actually visit the redirect page, then test for layout links after login.

This is my code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", signup_path
    get signup_path
    assert_select "title", full_title("Sign up")
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    get login_path
    assert_select "title", full_title("Log in")
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "h1", @user.name
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", users_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
  end
end
```